# lucene field.index wired phenomenon

Tags: lucene

when I add a field to document like this:

```
doc.add(new Field("name","Jack",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

I can get the hit when I search name:Jack

However, if I use Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED instead of Field.Index.ANALYZED, the program can't find the name:Jack, why?

Because the field which is Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED is also indexed, I think the field is searchable, but why I can't find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. But your query parser probably uses an analyzer which performs some operations on your tokens (like lowercasing). Try to use a KeywordAnalyzer at search time.

Alternatively, you could build the query yourself :

```
Query q = new TermQuery(new Term("name", "Jack"));
```

Comment: thank you, it works after analyzer is changed from SimpleAnalyzer to KeywordAnalyzer to search.

Comment: Fixes my answer. You are right, KeywordAnalyzer is even better than WhitespaceAnalyzer.